# SQL server 2005 connection in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello All i am connecting SQL server as a second database IN MY CODEIGNITER project the database is connected but i am not getting the data below is my configuration file and select query.

```
$db['database2'] = array (
    'hostname' => 'SERVER',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'DEMO',
    'database' => 'naaz',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

--controller

```
class Api extends CI_Controller {

    $db2 = '';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db2 = $this->load->database('database2',TRUE);
    }

    public function index() {

        $query = $this->db2->query('SELECT * FROM TIMEDATA');
        $result = $query->result_array();
        print_r($result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message or something? SQL 2005 is old and not really supported anymore

Comment: I am not getting any error I got just a blank array